# Slice getting changed after copying it and working with the copy

Tags: go

I wrote this code for making slice copy, and it is working fine, and the main slice that is passed as parameter to the function is not impacted:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Team []Person
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    team := Team{
        Person{"Hasan", 34}, Person{"Karam", 32},
    }
    fmt.Printf("original before clonning: %v\n", team)
    team_cloned := team.Clone()
    fmt.Printf("original after clonning: %v\n", team)
    fmt.Printf("clones slice: %v\n", team_cloned)
}

func (c *Team) Clone() Team {
    var s = make(Team, len(*c))
    copy(s, *c)
    for index, _ := range s {
        s[index].Name = "change name"
    }
    return s
}
```

But in my other code, the original slice is getting change even I'm passing a `clone` from it to the function:

```golang
type Inventories []Inventory
type Inventory struct { //instead of: map[string]map[string]Pairs
    Warehouse string
    Item      string
    Batches   Lots
}
type Lots []Lot
type Lot struct {
    Date  time.Time
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

func (c *Inventories) Clone() Inventories {
    var s = make(Inventories, len(*c))
    copy(s, *c)
    return s
}

func (outs Inventories) BuildBatchesFrom(ins Inventories) (batchesBalance Inventories, outgoing Inventories) {
    batchesOut := Inventories{}

    for _, in := range batchesBalance {
        for _, out := range outgoing {
            if out.Warehouse == in.Warehouse && out.Item == in.Item {
                batches := Lots{}
            OUTER:
                for {
                    oldestBatch := in.Batches.First()
                    batchQty := math.Min(in.Batches.First().Value, math.Abs(out.Batches.First().Value))

                    batches = append(batches, Lot{out.Batches.First().Date, oldestBatch.Key, batchQty})

                    out.Batches[0].Value = out.Batches.First().Value + batchQty
                    in.Batches[0].Value = oldestBatch.Value - batchQty

                    if in.Batches.First().Value == 0 {
                        in.Batches.PopFirst()
                    }
                    if out.Batches.First().Value == 0 {
                        out.Batches.PopFirst()
                        if len(out.Batches) == 0 {
                            break
                        } else {
                            continue OUTER
                        }
                    } else {
                        continue OUTER
                    }
                }
                batchesOut = append(batchesOut, Inventory{
                    Warehouse: out.Warehouse,
                    Item:      out.Item,
                    Batches:   batches,
                })
            }
        }
        //os.Exit(3)
    }
    return batchesOut, batchesBalance
} 

func main() {
ins := Inventory{
        Warehouse: "DMM",
        Item:      "Gloves",
        Batches: Lots{
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "1/7/2020")), "Jan", 50},
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "2/1/2020")), "Feb", 70},
        },
    }

outs := Inventory{
        Warehouse: "DMM",
        Item:      "Gloves",
        Batches: Lots{
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "1/5/2020")), "", -10},
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "2/9/2020")), "", -30},
        },
    }

        fmt.Printf("\n\n[1] Ins: \n%v", ins)     // This output is different after running outs_clone.BuildBatchesFrom(ins_clone)
    fmt.Printf("\n\n[2] Outs: \n%v", outs)   //  // This output is different after running outs_clone.BuildBatchesFrom(ins_clone)

        ins_clone := ins.Clone()
    outs_clone := outs.Clone()

    batchesOut, batchesBalance := outs_clone.BuildBatchesFrom(ins_clone)

    fmt.Printf("\n\n[1] Ins: \n%v", ins)    // This output is different before running outs_clone.BuildBatchesFrom(ins_clone)
    fmt.Printf("\n\n[2] Outs: \n%v", outs)   // This output is different after running outs_clone.BuildBatchesFrom(ins_clone)

    fmt.Printf("\n\n[4] Batches outs: \n%v", batchesOut)
    fmt.Printf("\n\n[5] Batches Balances: \n%v", batchesBalance)
}
```

In the above, `ins` is changing after running the function, though I'm not passing it there, and `ins_clone()` is changing after the function though I'm cloning it in the first line of the function code, same for `outs` and `outs_clone()`

Comment: This isn't quite a [mre], but offhand I can see that `Clone()` does not copy the `Batches` values.

Comment: I can not understand your code and it has many errors. But I think it's better to use `deepcopy.Copy` function to clone your object. This link may be useful:
https://godoc.org/github.com/getlantern/deepcopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the reason is that my slice contains a `sub slice` so the `copy` worked for the top one but did not work for the sub one, which is sharing same data, I fixed it by re-writing the code by creating a new slice, pushing the data to it, then use it to replace the original one, as beow:

```golang
func (i *Inventories) CloneFrom(c Inventories) {
    inv := new(Inventories)
    for _, v := range c {
        batches := Lots{}
        for _, b := range v.Batches {
            batches = append(batches, Lot{
                Date:  b.Date,
                Key:   b.Key,
                Value: b.Value,
            })
        }

        *inv = append(*inv, Inventory{
            Warehouse: v.Warehouse,
            Item:      v.Item,
            Batches:   batches,
        })
    }
    (*i).ReplaceBy(inv)
}

func (i *Inventories) ReplaceBy(x *Inventories) {
    *i = *x
}
```